# Change Text Font within Same Textbox in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have multiple subs within VBA that all have their output within the same text box (WarningData) in a PPT slide. For example, Sub 1 takes a user selection (a selection they made from a drop down menu within a GUI) and inserts that at the top of the text box. Sub 2 inserts another line of text below that line. Sub 3 inserts additional text below that. I need Sub 1 and 2 to have the same font style, but Sub 3 needs to have a different font.

Here is what Sub 1 and Sub 2 look like:

```
Private Sub 1() 'Sub 2 is very similar.
Call Dictionary.WindInfo

  'Sets the font for the warning information text.

   With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange.Font

    .Size = 24
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .Shadow.Visible = True
    .Glow.Radius = 10
    .Glow.Color = RGB(128, 0, 0)

   End With

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox3), CStr(ComboBox4))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList

   On Error Resume Next
   'If nothing is selected in ComboBox4, do nothing and exit this sub.
    If ComboBox4 = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    ElseIf ComboBox3 = "" Then
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange = _
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange & dict3.Item(Ky)(0)
    'Otherwise, if it has a selection, insert selected text.
    ElseIf ComboBox3 <> "" Then
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange = _
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict3.Item(Ky)(0)

    End If

 Next

Set dict3 = Nothing

End Sub
```

The following sub is the one that I need to have a different font style:

```
Private Sub 3()
Call Dictionary.Call2Action

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox7))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList

   On Error Resume Next
   'If nothing is selected in ComboBox7 and TextBox9, do nothing and exit this sub.
    If ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    'Otherwise, if either has a selection, insert selected text.
    ElseIf ComboBox7 <> "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange = _
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict7.Item(Ky)(0)
    ElseIf ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 <> "" Then
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange = _
     ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2.TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TextBox9

    End If

 Next

Set dict7 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend you give meaningful names to your controls. `TextBox9` and `ComboBox7` mean nothing in code, and make the maintenance of your VBA code ...a pain in the neck.

Comment: Good point. I will definitely do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the TextRange.Paragraphs method I was able to accomplish this task:

```
Private Sub 3()
Call Dictionary.Call2Action

ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox7))

   For Each Ky In ComboBoxList
     On Error Resume Next
     With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2
       'If nothing is selected in ComboBox7 and TextBox9, do nothing and exit this sub.
       If ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
       'Otherwise, if either has a selection, insert selected text.
       ElseIf ComboBox7 <> "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
         .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict7.Item(Ky)(0)
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Size = 18
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Name = "Calibri"
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Bold = msoTrue
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Glow.Transparency = 1
       ElseIf ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 <> "" Then
         .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TextBox9
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Size = 18
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Name = "Calibri"
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
         .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Font.Bold = msoTrue
       End If
     End With
   Next

   Set dict7 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Strange that .TextRange.Paragraphs(n) presently does not directly support .Font property. It is however possible to accomplish this by adding Range to Paragraph: .TextRange.Paragraphs(3).Range.Font.Bold = msoTrue

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code using a With statement and added 2 x font lines to show how to set the Font name. Other properties are also available in the Font2 object e.g. .Size, .Bold, .Fill etc.

```
Private Sub Three()
  Call Dictionary.Call2Action

  ComboBoxList = Array(CStr(ComboBox7))

  For Each Ky In ComboBoxList
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("WarningData").TextFrame2
      'If nothing is selected in ComboBox7 and TextBox9, do nothing and exit this sub.
      If ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
        Exit Sub
      'Otherwise, if either has a selection, insert selected text.
      ElseIf ComboBox7 <> "" And TextBox9 = "" Then
        .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & dict7.Item(Ky)(0)
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      ElseIf ComboBox7 = "" And TextBox9 <> "" Then
        .TextRange = .TextRange & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & TextBox9
        .TextRange.Font.Name = "Calibri"
      End If
    End With
  Next

  Set dict7 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Jamie. Unfortunately, when I do this, the text throughout all subs is still the same within the text box. I have subs 1 and 2 as a certain size with a glow and sub 3 has a smaller text size and no glow. If it helps, I can post the code for all three subs? Thanks!

Comment: It's working on my end so can you confirm the code is reaching/executing those .TextRange.Font.Name lines by inserting a Debug.Print "Here" line before them? Also, I would only use the line On Error Resume Next if you are going to process any errors generated otherwise it just masks them, leaving you a bit blind. I'd comment that out, at least while developing.